# Nginx daemon starts with "daemon off" directive

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I am using Nginx 1.4.6.

I set `daemon off;`  in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, than I do `nginx -s reload`, than `reboot`  and Nginx is still starting.

I even delete  `/etc/init.d/nginx` file and still starting.

How can I stop Nginx being a daemon? 
I wanna run it inside supervisor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*update-rc.d -f nginx remove*

This command removes all /etc/rc*/*nginx* symbolic links. At next boot, the service is not started.